# How to aggregate over unique values in Postgres with window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

**(Using Postgres 9.1)**

My program deals with insecticide sprayers attempting to spray a number of actual units based on an original target. For example, the sprayer Joe was supposed to spray 10 targets but he actually sprayed 7.

I am provided a table which is the summary of all planned targets (column= *targets*) and actual targets (column= *actual*), along with some other data, including the sprayer's name. Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE spray_summary
(
 id character varying(1),
 target integer,
 ref_id character varying(1),
 actual integer,
 sprayer character varying(25)
)
```

The data is a denormalized join between (id, target) and (ref_id, actual, sprayer), but for now this table is all I have to work with. Here's the full results:

```
SELECT * FROM spray_summary
```

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| id | target | ref_id | actual | sprayer |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| a  |      1 | "l"    |     10 | "Joe"   |
| a  |      1 | "m"    |     10 | "Joe"   |
| a  |      1 | "p"    |     10 | "Joe"   |
| c  |      3 | "n"    |     10 | "Joe"   |
| c  |      3 | "o"    |     10 | "Joe"   |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

You can see that *id* value "a" is repeated three times due to the one-to-many join and "c" repeats twice. Given this, what I want to do is show the SUM of *target* values, the SUM of "actual" values, and the sprayer. I used the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(target) targets, SUM(actual) actuals, sprayer FROM spray_summary GROUP BY sprayer
```

Which returned the result:

```
+--------+--------+---------+
| target | actual | sprayer |
+--------+--------+---------+
|      9 |     50 | "Joe"   |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

While the sum is correct (5 * 10 = 50) for *actual* values, the *target* values is being multiplied because the dataset is denormalized. I want "target" to be unique relative to *id* and *sprayer*, so I tried a window function:

```
SELECT SUM(target) OVER(PARTITION BY sprayer, id),
sprayer,
SUM(actual)
FROM spray_summary
GROUP BY sprayer, target, id
```

This gives me the results:

```
+--------+--------+---------+
| target | actual | sprayer |
+--------+--------+---------+
|      1 |     30 | "Joe"   |
|      3 |     20 | "Joe"   |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

Still not right! The right solution would give the following:

```
+--------+--------+---------+
| target | actual | sprayer |
+--------+--------+---------+
|      4 |     50 | "Joe"   |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

But no matter how much I try to tweak the window function the rows are split because I **have** to GROUP BY *target* which breaks up the rows. Any ideas? I know this can be rewritten by joining the table with itself, once for SUM *target* and once for SUM *actual*, but I don't have that option. I can **only** modify the column definitions.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I know this can be solved by pushing some of the logic into a sub-query, but I'm looking for a column-level solution if that's possible. The SQL is auto-generated, so I don't have much control over the structure, but I can modify the column definitions, hence I'm looking for a column-level solution, like a window function.

Worst case scenario is Postgres can't solve this at the column level and I'll have to re-write the SQL generators.

Comment: You can't aggregate the target before joining?

Comment: You can try to select from select but it is not a good use case for analytic query

Comment: One solution is to aggregate ahead of time, but this code is generated automatically via Java, and I don't have a lot of control over the entire structure, just the column values. It's an unfortunate restriction.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/62690/1)

```
select sum(target) as target, sum(actual) as actual, sprayer
from (
    select
        target,
        sum(actual) as actual,
        sprayer
    from spray_summary
    group by id, target, sprayer
) s
group by sprayer
order by sprayer
;
 target | actual | sprayer 
--------+--------+---------
      4 |     50 | joe
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without restructuring the query? The query is dynamically generated so I don't have much control over the structure, but I can modify the column definitions, hence I'm looking to something at the SELECT level.